# About "Equivalent Binary Tree" probelm

Tags: go

I am reading the tour of Go, it has a problem of equivalent binary tree. The article said A function to check whether two binary trees store the same sequence is quite complex in most languages.

https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/7

I am a little confused, could we just use any traversal method like inorder traversal the tree and verify the resulted sequence is same. I think it is pretty simple. Anyone could let me know if my understanding is wrong?

Comment: The difference would be that your suggestion requires: walking one tree and storing the results in a list or some such, then walking the other tree and storing the results in a list or some such, and then comparing the lists.  In the Go example, using channels, you can have one "thread" walking one tree and another "thread" walking the other tree, then compare the results as the pop out of their respective channels.  Note that each thread only "stores" one value on its channel, it blocks/waits until that value is received and then carries on.

Comment: Please [edit] the typo in your title, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's implicit in the problem definition that you're comparing whether two binary search trees contain the same multiset of elements, and while an in-order of a BST will give you the elements in sorted order, the same is not true of any other traversal. E.g. the tree ¹\₂ has preorder 12 while the tree ₁/² has preorder 21, despite that both contain the same elements.

Comment: We just use preorder to traverse the tree, then sort the result list, before comparing. I still don't see why it is complex.